# REST based web services the server returns more arrays than expected

Tags: php, rest

I am building a REST based web services, in the server, I have a service called display_all_products the code is like so:

```
case 'display_all_products':
    $KEY = filter_input(INPUT_GET, 'api_key');
    try {
        $token = JWT::decode($KEY, $secret);
        $jsonProducts = getProducts();
        $products = json_decode($jsonProducts, TRUE);
    } catch (Exception $ex) {
        return -1;
    }
    if($products != NULL){
        echo $jsonProducts;
    }else{
        echo "error";
    }
```

Function getProducts() will get all the products information from database and return a json string. When I tested the function, I got a json string like this:

```
[{"product_id":1,"0":1,"product_name":"Chocolate","1":"Chocolate","price":3,"2":3,"description":"Dark chocolate","3":"Dark chocolate"},{"product_id":2,"0":2,"product_name":"Toilet tissue","1":"Toilet tissue","price":10,"2":10,"description":"Nature and Soft","3":"Nature and Soft"},{"product_id":3,"0":3,"product_name":"Rice","1":"Rice","price":5,"2":5,"description":"Basmati Rice","3":"Basmati Rice"},{"product_id":4,"0":4,"product_name":"Fruit Loaf","1":"Fruit Loaf","price":5,"2":5,"description":"Rich Fruit Bread","3":"Rich Fruit Bread"},{"product_id":5,"0":5,"product_name":"Raspberry Jam","1":"Raspberry Jam","price":6,"2":6,"description":"Full of Flavour","3":"Full of Flavour"}]
```

It looks like a json string, nothing wrong with it. And also I can get it from the client which means I can do the json_decode in the code I provided above.

The problem is I can not do the json_decode in the client. When it comes to the client, I am getting a json string from the server like this:

```
[{"product_id":1,"0":1,"product_name":"Chocolate","1":"Chocolate","price":3,"2":3,"description":"Dark chocolate","3":"Dark chocolate"},{"product_id":2,"0":2,"product_name":"Toilet tissue","1":"Toilet tissue","price":10,"2":10,"description":"Nature and Soft","3":"Nature and Soft"},{"product_id":3,"0":3,"product_name":"Rice","1":"Rice","price":5,"2":5,"description":"Basmati Rice","3":"Basmati Rice"},{"product_id":4,"0":4,"product_name":"Fruit Loaf","1":"Fruit Loaf","price":5,"2":5,"description":"Rich Fruit Bread","3":"Rich Fruit Bread"},{"product_id":5,"0":5,"product_name":"Raspberry Jam","1":"Raspberry Jam","price":6,"2":6,"description":"Full of Flavour","3":"Full of Flavour"}][][]
```

Both of the json string are very similar but at the very end of the second json string has two more[] in there. I did not encode twice. I think that is the reason why I can not decode it but where are the two[] come from and how to get rid of them.

Here is my code form the client:

```
$keyReq = "?api_key=" . $api_key . "&service=display_all_products";
    $ch = curl_init();
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $basicUrl . $keyReq);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, TRUE);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HEADER, FALSE);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, array("Accept: application/json"));
    $jsonProducts = curl_exec($ch);

    curl_close($ch);
    $products = json_decode($jsonProducts, TRUE);
```

Comment: Got any `break` statements in that `switch`? If I had to guess, I'd say some other _service_ calls are executing due to [case fallthrough](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Switch_statement#Fallthrough)

Comment: Yes，there are five services in the server so I have five break statements.

Comment: OK，I see what you mean.

Comment: Was that the problem then?

Comment: There are two more services below that, the two [] might indicate two arrays from the them. The problem might be case fallthrough but I only want to call the display_all_products service and return only one json string.